# iAd showing test advertisement on some devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, iad

I released an iOS app 1 week ago with iAd banner. On my wife's iPad the iAds show up normally. However on my iPad and iPhone they keep displaying test advertisement.

I've searched thru the site and google, removed the development version and downloaded the distributed app from app store, even reset the settings of my iPad still showing test advertisement.

I don't think it's an issue from apple since my wife's device is seeing real ads, it must be something for my iPad but I couldn't figure out...

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add your iPad as an testing device and then forgot to remove it?

Comment: If your iPad is set as testing device in developer account and provisional certificate is installed in your device then the device will show only Test Ads

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers! I don't think I ever added my iPad as a testing device but I can be wrong. It's my first time developing iOS app. Could you tell me how I can check/remove a testing device?   I went to the provisioning center, then device tab and deleted my iPad in the device list since yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution myself -> what I did is to use "restore" in iTunes to wipe my device - that solves the issue. If you had same issue as I did and couldn't find other way, this will do the trick :)